# How to change Amazon echo Alexa's Name to something else?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I thought of buying Amazon Echo Dot but I have one problem with that.Is there is a way to change Alexa's name to someting else.

Instead of asking,

*"Alexa, what's the time now"*

Is it possible to ask like

*"Jhon, Whats the time now"*

Thanks ,

Mohammed

Comment: And Guys , I am not sure this type of question can be asked here. As there is  "Alexa" tag, i added this question here.Please correct me if i am wrong.And Please don't DOWNVOTE it, If am wrong.Comment down here I will delete this QUESTION. If this is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is provided by default :

https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201971890

But if you are not satisfied with it, i am not sure if its possible on the device you are using . but on my device {***made using raspberryPi***} it works by changing some code.

```
pocketsphinx:
enabled: true
voice_confirm: true

phrase: "alexa"
threshold: 1e-10
```

> on location :   /etc/opt/AlexaPi/config.yaml

As far as I know, custom wake words are only supported on the Raspberry Pi Amazon Alexa bit of kit.

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-build-your-own-amazon-echo-with-a-raspberry-pi-1787726931

Hope this will give you the clear picture what you are expecting and what exactly is there.

[UPDATE] try this new link for Alexa Pi :    https://lifehacker.com/the-simplest-way-to-build-a-raspberry-pi-powered-amazon-1794218212

Answer (score -2):

I think for these boards you're supposed to research first before posting, but fwiw here is some help:

http://nymag.com/selectall/2017/01/how-to-change-amazon-echo-alexas-name-to-something-else.html

**From the referenced article by Madison Kircher:**

Step 1: Open the Alexa app.

Step 2: Tap the three horizontal lines next to “Home” in the upper-left-hand corner of the screen.

Step 3: Tap “Settings” from the menu.

Step 4: Select the device you want to change. If you only own one, this should be easy.

Step 5: Tap “Wake Word.” You’ll be shown a menu of options: “Amazon,” “Echo,” and “Computer.” Pick one to be your new command. Heads up: Changing the wake word can take a few minutes to update on the device itself, so you’ll have to wait a little bit before returning to yelling at your little robot to play you some Alanis Morissette.

Comment: A link without explanation doesn't constitute an answer as the link might be disabled in future. Provide explanation along with link

Comment: the question was to know if it is possible to ask like

"Jhon, Whats the time now" ?